# GitHub Actions: How to use Docker image from GitHub registry in a Docker action?

Tags: python-3.x, docker, dockerfile, github-actions

I recently created my first Docker container action, and it works perfectly as intended. The Dockerfile for this action uses `python:3.9-slim`. It looks like this:

```
FROM python:3.9-slim

COPY repo ./repo
COPY scripts ./scripts
COPY requirements.txt setup.py ./
COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh

RUN python setup.py develop

ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

I'm now thinking of publishing the Docker image from the above Dockerfile on Docker/GitHub registry and using it in the Docker action. Essentially the idea is to simplify the image build process, so the action can run faster.

I have a couple of questions related to doing this, #1 is the question in the title:

1. I found this [page](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/guides/publishing-docker-images) which explains how to have a workflow to publish the Docker image. If I publish to GitHub registry, how can I go about using it? For images on Docker, that seems straightforward.
2. With this Docker container action, I want to make sure that it uses the version specified in `uses: username/action-repo@v???`. Thus, I think it would make sense to have the FROM in this new Dockerfile configured for the specific image tag that will be used. Is that the best way to go about it?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood everything correctly, but regarding your question title, you could create a folder in your repo with your Docker Image Dockerfile (and publish it through a specific workflow), having the action Dockerfile using this image at the root of the repository.

Comment: Apologies as the title perhaps wasn't as clear.

Comment: @GuiFalourd after some thinking I think the bigger question is using a Docker image that is stored on the GitHub registry. My search for GitHub Actions and Docker returns a lot of Docker registry specific stuff.